# Is there a way to keep the ArrayList as a local variable?

Tags: java, recursion

```
public static ArrayList<String> searchFiles(File currentFolder) throw NotDirectoryException {
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    if(!currentFolder.isDirectory())
      throw new NotDirectoryException("File is not a directory");
    File[] direct = currentFolder.listFiles();
    if(direct!=null) {
      for (int i = 0; i< direct.length; i++){
        if(direct[i].isDirectory())
          searchFiles(direct[i]);
        if(direct[i].isFile()&&!direct[i].isHidden())
        result.add(direct[i].getName());
      }
    }
  return result;
  }
```

The purpose of this code is to search through all directories and sub directories and then add the eligible files into an arraylist recursively. The code works fine if I remove the ArrayList declaration from the method and put it instead as a global varible, it will correctly add all files in the directories into the arraylist. If i keep it as a local variable, it only adds the files in the root folder and nothing else. Is there a way to keep the ArrayList as a local variable while making the code work?

Comment: You are ignoring the return value of `searchFiles` when you call it recursively.

Comment: The public method could create the list, and delegate to a private method which does the actual recursion.  This would avoid the caller from having to pass in an empty list.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the `ArrayList` to the recrsive call as shown below:

```
public static ArrayList<String> searchFiles(File currentFolder, ArrayList<String> result) throw NotDirectoryException {
    if(!currentFolder.isDirectory()) 
        throw new NotDirectoryException("File is not a directory");
    File[] direct = currentFolder.listFiles();
    if(direct!=null) {
        for (int i = 0; i< direct.length; i++){
            if(direct[i].isDirectory())
                searchFiles(direct[i], result);
            if(direct[i].isFile()&&!direct[i].isHidden())
                result.add(direct[i].getName());
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Note that when you declare `result` as a local variable, it will be destroyed after the method will return. In order to preserve its value, you can pass it as a parameter while calling the method recursively.

Comment: How would `result` remain a local variable, then?

Comment: @fps - What is the use of keeping `result` as a local variable?

Comment: It's in the title of the question, OP wants the array list as a local variable

Comment: @fps - OP is not so matured but you are. We need to educate new programmers if they make mistakes.

Comment: I agree. Please explain why your way is better, then, so that beginners can learn from your answer

Comment: @fps - Valid suggestion. Updated my answer to explain it better.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222426/discussion-between-fps-and-arvind-kumar-avinash).

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is properly use the return value of `searchFiles` in the recursion.  For example, instead of

```
searchFiles(direct[i]);
```

write

```
result.addAll(searchFiles(direct[i]));
```

Passing the mutable `ArrayList` recursively in other answers is more efficient, but more confusing, and is best paired with a public overload of the method without the `ArrayList` parameter.  Additionally, this would violate your question's title, which specifies that the `ArrayList` should remain a local variable.

Comment: Entries added for a subdirectory could end up being copied several times before they make it into the top level result list, so I'd say the potential overhead this solution introduces outweighs the cons of the other solution, by a lot.

Comment: @jingx But OP asked that way: the array list must remain a local variable. Of course it's more efficient to pass it as an argument, and even to do this iteratively, but that's not what OP has asked

Comment: That's a fair point to keep this answer a valid solution, admittedly the only valid one even, but not a fair point of itself. I don't see any practical reason to keep the result list a local variable.

Comment: @jingx I don't, either. Much better to pass it as a parameter and accumulate partial results there. Maybe OP doesn't know this or wants to not pass partial result as argument

Answer (score 0):

Pass in the arraylist. The original caller would pass in a new ArrayList()

Comment: How would `result` be a local variable, then?

Comment: You need an accumulator. Each of your recursive subroutines are doing part of the work, you need a common place to store all the results. You have two choices 1. Pass it in. 2. Make it global.

Comment: I understand that. I also agree in that having an accumulator is better that returning the list as in the other answer. But I think you should explain why your way is better

Comment: Not better, 6 of one half a dozen of the other.